# Entering data into an HTML table

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I begin by saying that I have a web page in which there are text areas in which I enter data. There is also a button, and through it I should write the data entered in a table of the DB, and display the same data on a table in another web page. Now, the first part, that is to write the data on the DB I was able to complete it, the second one however not.
Would anyone be able to help me? below I leave you the HTML, JavaScript and C # server side they can be useful.

HTML

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <button id ="Aggiungi" class="button2" onclick="redirect()">+</button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <table id= "tabel" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id ="col">NOME</th><th id ="col">COGNOME</th>
                    <th id ="col">AZIENDA</th>
                    <th id ="col">PROVINCIA</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>  

        <br/>
    </form>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```js
function add() {       
     let nom = document.getElementById("nome").value;
     let cognom = document.getElementById("cognome").value;
     let aziend = document.getElementById("azienda").value;
     let provincia = document.getElementById("provincia").value;        

    if ((nom == "") || (nom == "undefined") || (cognom == "") || (cognom == "undefined") || (aziend == "") || (aziend == "undefined") || (provincia == "") || (provincia == "undefined")) {

        alert("Inserire i dati per favore");            
    } else {  
        let dati = { nome: nom, cognome: cognom, azienda: aziend, provin: provincia };
        
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "user-form.aspx/ScriviDati",
             data: JSON.stringify(dati),
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             global: false,
             async: false,
             success: function (a) {

                 console.log(a.d);
                 alert("Perfetto")
             },

             fail: function (response) {
                 alert("Qualcosa è andato storto");
             }
         });
    }
}
```

C#

```cs
public static void ScriviDati (string nome, string cognome, string azienda, string provin)
{
    string queryString = "INSERT Elenco (Nome, Cognome, Azienda, Provincia) VALUES (@Nome, @Cognome, @Azienda, @Provincia)";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["coso"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
        {
            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("Nome", nome);
            SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter("Cognome", cognome);
            SqlParameter parameter3 = new SqlParameter("Azienda", azienda);
            SqlParameter parameter4 = new SqlParameter("Provincia", provin);
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter2);
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter3);
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter4);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only button I can see calls redirect(), not add()

Comment: yes I know, that is the table present on another html page on which I would like to insert the incoming data. That button is totally unrelated to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="tabel" class="display">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="col">A</th>
          <th id="col">B</th>
          <th id="col">C</th>
          <th id="col">D</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </body>
  <script>
    window.onload = function () {
      const data = [
        { A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, D: 4 },
        { A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, D: 4 },
        { A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, D: 4 },
        { A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, D: 4 },
      ];

      const table = document.querySelector("table");
      data.forEach((item, index) => {
        let tr = document.createElement("tr");

        for (const key in item) {
          let td = document.createElement("td");
          td.innerText = item[key];
          tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
      });
    };
  </script>
</html>
```